# Can we convert a website which is not created for mobile , in mobile-view using WebSettings in android

Tags: android

I have a website "http://aptapp.mobi/" , when i am accessing it .... via my code

```
    WebView browser = ( WebView ) findViewById ( R.id.webkit );
    browser.loadUrl("http://aptapp.mobi");
```

its in desktop version ( not created for mobiles ) , but when i am using **WebSettings** provided by android ...

```
    WebSettings web = browser.getSettings();
    web.setUserAgent(0);
```

but it is not converted into , mobile-view using this ......

Comment: i am using webview , but i want to access my website ( which is not created for mobile devices ) ..... in a form of mobile-view not in a desktop-view .

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it. You can view the desktop-view in the mobile but without creating the mobile version for the particular web you can't see in the browser in mobile view.

That's why Many companies and communities made mobile version site for their web site.

So, without creating it specifically not possible to have it in mobile version view.

Hope you got my point.